# Loop to check matches in several arrays

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode, loops

I have 7 arrays of `Strings`.

```
var redArray : [String] = ["2022-07-13", "2022-07-14","2022-07-15"]
var blueArray : [String] = ["2022-07-13", "2022-07-14","2022-07-16"]
...
And five more of the same format
```

I'm trying to create a method that will go through seven arrays and work like the following one (example below works for two arrays):

```
       if redArray.contains(someDate) && blueArray.contains(someDate)
        {
            return [UIColor.red, UIColor.blue]
        }
        else
        
        if redArray.contains(someDate)
        {
            return [UIColor.red]
        }
        else if blueArray.contains(someDate)
        {
            return [UIColor.blue]
        }

        return [UIColor.clear]
```

So it should find matches of dates in arrays and return an `UIColor` of arrays with this matches. In case there is no match - a single colour should be returned. It's easy to do it for two arrays. But I don't understand how can I loop through 7 of them :(

Of course, it can be done manually. But I guess there must be a smart way to implement the `loop` - though I'm not smart enough to figure it out how.

P.S. I don't know, if it is important, but the `function` where this method will be used is the following:

```
func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, appearance: FSCalendarAppearance,eventDefaultColorsFor date: Date) -> [UIColor]?
    {
       ...
    }
```

Comment: What about creating grouping the seven arrays? Into a Dictionary where keys could be colors or in an array of tuples which values would be colors and the array. Iterate/filter the array, and get back the colors ? Or simply create an `[UIColor]`, iterate over the arrays, each times it contains the correct value, append the correct color?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply do that:

```
var colors: [UIColor] = []

if redArray.contains(someData) {
    colors.append(.red)
}
if blueArray.contains(someData) {
    colors.append(.blue)
}
if greenArray.contains(someData) {
    colors.append(.green)
}

return colors.isEmpty ? [.clear] : colors
```

If you really want loops, starting with:

```
let tuples: [(UIColor, [String])] = [(.red, redArray), (.blue, blueArray), (.green, greenArray)]
var colors: [UIColor] = []
```

Basic for loop:

```
for aTuple in tuples {
    if aTuple.1.contains(someData) {
        colors.append(aTuple.0)
    }
}
```

Basic for loop with `where`:

```
for aTuple in tuples where aTuple.1.contains(someData) {
    colors.append(aTuple.0)
}
```

With a `forEach`:

```
tuples.forEach {
    if $0.1.contains(someData) {
        colors.append($0.0)
    }
}
```

If you prefer `reduced(into:_:)`:

```
let colors = tuples.reduce(into: [UIColor]()) { partialResult, current in
    guard current.1.contains(someData) else { return }
    partialResult.append(current.0)
}
```

And still `return colors.isEmpty ? [.clear] : colors` at the end.

Edit: [As suggested in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73005738/loop-to-check-matches-in-several-arrays/73005845?noredirect=1#comment128946228_73005845), there is also the `compactMap()` solution. It can be seen as a `map()` + `filter()` in one loop.

```
let colors = tuples.compactMap { aTuple in
    if aTuple.1.contains(someData) {
        return aTuple.0
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to do this in a single expression, `reduce` is overkill. `filter`+`map` or `compactMap` can do, e.g. `let colors = tuples.filter { _colour, colourArray in colourArray.contains(someDate) }.map { colour, _colourArray in colour }` or `let colors = tuples.compactMap { _colour, colourArray in colourArray.contains(someDate) ? colour : nil }`

Comment: Indeed, good idea. filter+map will do two loop (which as said on other solution, might be not a real issue with small array)

Comment: Larme, thank you very much for your help! Extraordinary detailed and clear explanation.

Comment: @Larme eh, this is these kinds of loops are exactly the kinda thing the optimizer should be able to merge easily and reliably. I’ll have a deeper look later when I have time

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
func loop(someDate: String, arrays: [([String], UIColor)]) -> [UIColor] {
    let containingArrays = arrays.filter({$0.0.contains(someDate)})
    return containingArrays.isEmpty ? [.clear]: containingArrays.map({$0.1})
}
```

Usage: `loop(someDate: "some Date", arrays: [(["Test1"], .red), (["Test2"], .blue)])`

Comment: The downside, just to point it out, in case of having a lot of array, would be that you are iterating twice: One in `filter()` and one in `map()`. Which for small array, wouldn't make a big differences

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I really like your `reduce` solution!